# Fill max-width before max-height?

Tags: css

I have div element with min-width, min-height, max-width, and max-height styling applied. The div will simply contain text.

The desired behavior I want is for the div to grow horizontally to fit the contents until it reaches max-width, and only then, I want the height to increase towards max-height as needed to fit the text contents.

The behavior right now is that the div stays at min-width and expands veritcally. How can I get the desired behavior?

UPDATE: The code:

```
.tooltip-body
{
    max-width: 265px;
    min-width: 200px;

    min-height: 34px;
    max-height: 46px;
}
```

---

```
<div class="tooltip-body">And the text goes here...</div>
```

Comment: CSS isn't smart enough to do this. You need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Try to put your max-width property after max-height.

Comment: @TiyebBellal Tried this, it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry but after I changed the value of  max-width to 865px it started to work just fine!!. A strange behaviour!.